Spring Cloud Stream testing pollable supplier
I'm having a code like following:
public class MyMessagesSupplier implements Supplier<Flux<Message<String>>> {

    @Override
    @PollableBean
    public Flux<Message<String>> get() {
        return Flux.just(MessageBuilder.createMessage("My message", new MessageHeaders(Map.of())));
    }
}

And I have a corresponding cloud config that triggers this bean, like:
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myMessagesSupplier-out-0.procuder.poller.fixed-delay=60000

And I'm wondering if there is a way to test it via org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-test-binder or any way to trigger the scheduler so I can assert on messages produced to myMessagesSupplier-out-0 channel. Please help!

This works for me:
Application:
@SpringBootApplication
public class So78484341Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So78484341Application.class, args);
    }

    @PollableBean
    public Supplier<Flux<Message<String>>> supplier() {
        return () -> Flux.just(MessageBuilder.createMessage("My message", new MessageHeaders(Map.of())));
    }

}

Test:
@SpringBootTest
@Import(TestChannelBinderConfiguration.class)
class So78484341ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private OutputDestination outputDestination;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        Message<byte[]> receive = outputDestination.receive(5000, "supplier-out-0");
        assertThat(new String(receive.getPayload(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).isEqualTo("My message");
    }
}

If you want to test the Supplier in a controlled manner, you can set the auto-startup on the binding to be false:
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.supplier-out-0.producer.auto-startup=false

Then in the test:
@SpringBootTest
@Import(TestChannelBinderConfiguration.class)
class So78484341ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private OutputDestination outputDestination;

    @Autowired
    private BindingsLifecycleController controller;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        List<Binding<?>> bindings = controller.queryState("supplier-out-0");
        Binding<?> binding = bindings.get(0);
        if (!binding.isRunning()) {
            binding.start();
        }
        Message<byte[]> receive = outputDestination.receive(5000, "supplier-out-0");
        assertThat(new String(receive.getPayload(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).isEqualTo("My message");
    }
}


Yeah, this is what I have so far as well. I was wondering of there is some more controlled way of triggering the poll from the test itself

Updated the answer with some strategies to test the Supplier in a controlled manner.
